# What happens when rosbag record runs out of diskspace?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

what will happen if I rosbag record ROS topics and don't have enough memory to store it? Will rosbag overwrite something  or will automatic shutdown command ?

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399709/what-happens-when-rosbag-record-runs-out-of-diskspace?/) by [dembele123](https://answers.ros.org/users/54011/dembele123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-26**:\

> Will rosbag overwrite something [..]?

you mean random other files on your file system?

No, that's not what will happen. I know of no program that would do that.

---

Edit: I've updated the title of your post, as "rosbag question" doesn't really capture what you really want to know -- and is too generic in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the option `--max-splits=MAX_SPLITS` solves this problem for you:

> Split bag at most MAX_SPLITS times,
> then begin deleting the oldest files.
> This creates a fixed size or duration
> recording.

`rosbag record --split --size 1024 --max-splits 3 /chatter` for size (in MB)

`rosbag record --split --duration 10m --max-splits 6 /chatter` for duration (in minutes)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1